# Getting "specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application" running Tomcat via Sysdeo under eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, sysdeo

Windows 7, eclipse Kepler; I have an existing application which I believe to be compiled with 32-bit java.  In any event, it won't work with 64-bit, that failed first.

So I downloaded and installed 32-bit eclipse and 32-bit java, set the path variable to pick up the java bin directory first (64-bit java was installed in \Windows\System32, and I don't want to try to uninstall it from there).  Rebooted several times; finally established that, on a command line, java -version gives the 32-bit version ins of the 64-bit.

So I can run eclipse and I can run Tomcat, no error.  I have double-checked the tomcat settings under Sysdeo to ensure they point to the newly-installed 32-bit version of java.

However, when I run the web application, I get "specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".  From googling that message, I gather it means I have a 64-bit driver and a 32-bit application.  So how do I reset things to use the 32-bit driver?

I noticed that a message on Tomcat startup: "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production enviornments was not found on the java.library.path:", and then it gives the following in a one-line harder-to-read form:

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/../jre/bin/client
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/../jre/bin
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/../jre/lib/i386
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\
C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64
C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\
C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\syswow64
C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\
C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\syswow64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Lenovo
C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse
```

So the first line indicates, perhaps, that another 64-bit version of java is STILL getting referenced, this time from "c:\program files\java\jre7\bin".  But I can't find where that's set, or where to unset it from.

Keep in mind that I don't have a project involved yet.  This is all to set up running tomcat from within eclipse using sysdeo, so I don't have "Project / Properties / Build Path".  I have "Windows / Preferences / Build path"; I have made sure the 32-bit version is the default JRE and has its correct path, but the Preferences / Java / build path / classpath variables are either deprecated or don't refer to java runtime at all (there's one pointing to 32-bit), and the only user library is xerces, hardly relevant to all this.

Can anyone please help me out on the correct settings for making this work, or methods for figuring it out?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that altering the path variable is not enough -- I found both a 64-bit and a 32-bit install of Java under Windows / Control Panel / Uninstall a Program; I uninstalled the 64-bit version, and now the application starts correctly.